# Explanation needed why $\int_a^bf(x)\sin (kx)dx=-f(x)\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}|^{b}_a+\frac{1}{k}\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\cos(kx)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F(k)$ be $\int_a^bf(x)\sin (kx)dx$. The book says that applying partial integration gives the result.

I have difficulties to understand how to deduce from partial integration this formula and hope somebody can help me.

When using partial integration one has two functions $f$ and $g$. $f$ remains $g$ is $\sin kx$. When I am using the formula for partial integration  $\int_a^bf(x)g'(x)dx=f(x)g(x)|^{b}_a-\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)g(x)dx$ I get $F(k)=-f(x)\cos(kx)|^{b}_a-\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\sin(kx)dx$.

Which is different from what is written in the title

Comment: You want $g'(x)=\sin kx$.

Comment: Chain rule warrants the $\frac1k$, if that is what confuses you.

Comment: You wrongly integrate $\sin(kx)$.

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you integrate $\sin(kx) $ the answer is $(-1/k )\cos(kx)$

You have apparently missed the $1/k$ part.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=-\dfrac{\cos kx}{k}$ and $g'(x) = \sin kx$. Then,

$$F(k)=\int_a^bf(x)\sin kx\, dx= \int_a^bf(x)g'(x)dx$$
$$=-f(x)\frac{\cos kx}{k}\bigg|^{b}_a+\frac1k\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\cos kx\, dx$$